# How communal parenting, through the develpment in the prefrontal cortex, could lead to a better emotion regulation?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, emotion, brain-development, parenting

In this [Michael Meaney interview](https://www.technologynetworks.com/neuroscience/articles/the-neurobiology-of-stress-with-professor-michael-meaney-323347), he let an open question at the end. He mentioned that communal parenting, could "*in some ways buffer the child by having potentially more positive sources of resilience in their lives*". I know the *amygdala* and *medial prefrontal cortex* are brain regions important for emotion regulation, however, how communal parenting could change their development and be an explanation for this to happen?

This is the interview last question (to avoid the link):

> **Interviewer**: Have there been studies of the influence of care
> in societies where the burden of care might be moved between parents
> or is it reasonably constant across societies?
>
> **Michael Meaney**: *No. We think it’s really interesting and it’s a dynamic. The psychologists speak, for example, of a child as being an
> organism that’s remarkably good at seeking out nurturance from
> whatever source may be there.  We see in Asia that many children are
> raised by grandparents or in a more communal environment. In a cohort
> that we run in Singapore, I believe that in 50% of the cases the
> mother is not the primary care giver in terms of the person who spends
> the most amount of time with the child.  That wouldn’t be true up to
> one year of life, but beyond one year it’s very often that children
> are raised by others, particularly grandparents. People are living in
> larger, extended families. The irony there is that these care
> structures may come closer to the original organization of the family
> who lived in kin groups. In fact, it may be that we in the west are
> somehow the outliers having created these nuclear families in which
> parenting and child care is so closely linked to one or two
> individuals whereas in other societies it can be far more communal.
> That leads you to some interesting outcomes. For example, a colleague
> of ours in Singapore was looking at the association between a common
> feature of early maternal care, which is sensitivity – to what extent
> is the mother attuned to the cues of the infant? She had a predicted a
> relationship between development in the prefrontal cortex and maternal
> sensitivity.  She’s seen a rather weak relationship, which surprised
> her, so she took this large sample she had and she split it and for
> those whom the mother was the primary care giver, she saw a very
> strong relationship between maternal sensitivity and prefrontal
> development, but for those children for whom the mother wasn’t the
> primary caregiver, it was absent.*  ***So I think in these particular
> instances, you’re seeing more diversity within the child care
> environment and I think it’s an excellent question to ask, does this
> in some ways buffer the child by having potentially more positive
> sources of resilience in their lives?  It’s a question well worth
> noting***.

Comment: I don't think he's saying exactly that.  He's saying that research has established a strong connection between primary caregiver sensitivity and prefrontal cortex development (presumably leading to emotional resilience later in life).  He then asks if having multiple caregivers may increase the chance that at least one of them is high in sensitivity, leading to a greater chance of prefrontal development (and hence greater resilience).

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg I got your point. Didn't thought that way. I believed that the caregiver time was distributed, not shared, and because the mother sensitivity was not necessarily correlated in those cases, I was thinking more in an average sensitivity between caregivers instead in the better one between all them. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Closing as [answered in comments](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2163/7001).